# Android Long Press

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, long-press

I have to implement a functionality in my application. It is just like iphone native functionality when we long press on any app icon then delete button should appear on all the icons and they can be deletable. Is this possible in Android?? Please let me know if it is feasible in Android or not??
Please don't vote down just let me know the feasibility.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible in android.

Comment: ok Thanks Hardik. Can you please help me regarding the same. I just first want to make a sample of the same.

Comment: why should people not vote down? Vote down are an indication to the OP owner intended to help me improve the OP itself

Comment: Blackbelt if you can help me please help me brother.

Comment: Hardik , Blackbelt please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, see below for help:-

```
@Override
 public void onLongPress(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.d("onLongPress",ev.toString());
 }
```